# How to implement Custom Suggestions in SearchView from fragment

Tags: search, android-fragments, searchview, search-suggestion

i have a view pager with 3 fragment one of the fragment
 have searchview widget and i get to know that i can,t implement the standard search interface so i implement some thing like this but how to implement Custom Suggestions in SearchView

```
public class LoaderCursor extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

        // Create the list fragment and add it as our sole content.
        if (fm.findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) {
            CursorLoaderListFragment list = new CursorLoaderListFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, list).commit();
        }
    }

    public static class CursorLoaderListFragment extends ListFragment
            implements OnQueryTextListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

        // This is the Adapter being used to display the list's data.
        SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

        // If non-null, this is the current filter the user has provided.
        String mCurFilter;

        @Override public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            // Give some text to display if there is no data.  In a real
            // application this would come from a resource.
            setEmptyText("No phone numbers");

            // We have a menu item to show in action bar.
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);

            // Create an empty adapter we will use to display the loaded data.
            mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, null,
                    new String[] { Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, Contacts.CONTACT_STATUS },
                    new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 }, 0);
            setListAdapter(mAdapter);

            // Start out with a progress indicator.
            setListShown(false);

            // Prepare the loader.  Either re-connect with an existing one,
            // or start a new one.
            getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
        }

        @Override public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            // Place an action bar item for searching.
            MenuItem item = menu.add("Search");
            item.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search);
            item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
            SearchView sv = new SearchView(getActivity());
            sv.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
            item.setActionView(sv);
        }

        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            // Called when the action bar search text has changed.  Update
            // the search filter, and restart the loader to do a new query
            // with this filter.
            mCurFilter = !TextUtils.isEmpty(newText) ? newText : null;
            getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);
            return true;
        }

        @Override public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            // Don't care about this.
            return true;
        }

        @Override public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            // Insert desired behavior here.
            Log.i("FragmentComplexList", "Item clicked: " + id);
        }

        // These are the Contacts rows that we will retrieve.
        static final String[] CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION = new String[] {
            Contacts._ID,
            Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            Contacts.CONTACT_STATUS,
            Contacts.CONTACT_PRESENCE,
            Contacts.PHOTO_ID,
            Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,
        };

        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
            // This is called when a new Loader needs to be created.  This
            // sample only has one Loader, so we don't care about the ID.
            // First, pick the base URI to use depending on whether we are
            // currently filtering.
            Uri baseUri;
            if (mCurFilter != null) {
                baseUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                        Uri.encode(mCurFilter));
            } else {
                baseUri = Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
            }

            // Now create and return a CursorLoader that will take care of
            // creating a Cursor for the data being displayed.
            String select = "((" + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND ("
                    + Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1) AND ("
                    + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " != '' ))";
            return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), baseUri,
                    CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select, null,
                    Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
        }

        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
            // Swap the new cursor in.  (The framework will take care of closing the
            // old cursor once we return.)
            mAdapter.swapCursor(data);

            // The list should now be shown.
            if (isResumed()) {
                setListShown(true);
            } else {
                setListShownNoAnimation(true);
            }
        }

        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
            // This is called when the last Cursor provided to onLoadFinished()
            // above is about to be closed.  We need to make sure we are no
            // longer using it.
            mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
        }
    }
}
```